# Task.Delay使用時、WPFでプロパティの値がリアルタイムに更新されない

Tags: c#

以下のようなシンプルなコードを動かした場合、Labelの値がリアルタイムに更新されません。正確にはウィンドウを動かすと値が更新され、何も触らないでいると更新されません。描画更新が止まっているような、そんな感じがあります。また、async/await をやめると1秒は待ってくれませんが値の更新は高速に行われます。

バックグラウンドで値を1秒ごとに更新するようなWPFアプリは作成できないのでしょうか？

```csharp
// MainWindow.xaml
/*
<Window x:Class="WpfApp32.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp32"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="{Binding Value}" Height="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
*/

// MainWindow.xaml.cs

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp32
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new MainWindowVM();
        }
    }

    public class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int Value { get; set; } = 0;

        public MainWindowVM()
        {
            Task.Run(async () => {
                while (true)
                {
                    Value++;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 正確(ある程度)な時間間隔が欲しいなら、DelayとかよりもTimerイベントを使った方が良いのでは？ [C#の4つのTimerの用途と使い方](https://takap-tech.com/entry/2017/09/09/225342)

Comment: こちらの環境で同じソースを実行した所、特に問題なくリアルタイムで更新されているようです。(VS2017、Framework4.6.1)

Comment: こちらでも問題なく動作することを確認しました(VS2019、.NET 5.0)。環境によるのかもしれませんので環境情報を追記したほうが良いかと思います。

Comment: もう少し調べていると、デバッグ実行しているときに描画がカクつくような動作になります。「デバッグなしで開始」で実行すると問題なく動作するようです。私の環境は(VS2019の .NET 5.0)でした。.Net Framework 4.8 でも試しましたが現象は変わらずでした。

Comment: ホットリロードの設定を無効にしたら問題なく動作しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この現象はデバッグ実行しているときのみ発生し、ホットリロードが設定されていることが原因でした。Visual Studio の [ツール(T)] → [オプション(O)] からオプションを開き、[デバッグ] → [XAMLホットリロード] の設定項目の [XAML ホットリロードを有効にする] をオフにすることで今回の問題は解決しました。